# required powersupply for AMD Radeon HD 7950?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

From AMD site the required powersupply for 7950 is 500W.

http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7950/Pages/radeon-7950.aspx#2

whereas when using custom configurator in ibuypower.com

http://www.ibuypower.com/Store/Intel_Z68_Core_i3_i5_i7_Configurator

it is saying the 7950 requires 750W powersupply.

I currently have AMD HD 6850 on 700W powersupply. I am planning to buy 7950, so I was wondering if 700W is sufficient? or do I need 750W?

I have Intel® Core™ i5-2500 Processor (4x 3.30GHz/6MB L3 Cache) with 4GB RAM ( which I purchased from ibuypower.com some time ago )

Comment: Your power requirement isn't determined by just the video card, but the video card + all other components.  If you have a 7950 + 10 hard drives you'll need a larger PSU than a 7950 + 1 SSD.  But probably a 700W PSU is sufficient for a single CPU, single GPU setup.

Comment: @BenVoigt I have single 500 GB HARD DRIVE -- 16M Cache, 7200 RPM, 6.0Gb/s. So, I think 700W PSU is sufficient. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this power calculator](http://www.extreme.outervision.com/psucalculatorlite.jsp), the difference between the two graphics cards is about 30 W, so I'd guess you'll be fine. I did a rough calculation based on what you supplied and it recommended 312 W.

Answer (score 0):

With basic components attached (power for mobo, 4 sticks of ram, 1 HDD, 1 optical drive and this new vid card) you are fine at 700w. Even with a few case fans and USB devices you are good.